# How do items in the 'Applications' folder get on the path?

Tags: path, macos, web-browser, environment-variables

How does the 'Applications' folder get on the path?

For example, I installed Chrome browser into the Applications folder on my Mac and I can type `chrome` at a bash shell prompt to start it.  Now, if I type `which chrome`, I get nothing, and therefore it doesn't reveal itself: how it got on the path.

BUT, on the other hand, if I move Chrome to my own custom `/opt/local/applications` folder, running with `chrome` no longer works and neither will it work if I add this to the path:  `/opt/local/applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS` .  I am trying to understand this so I can get Chrome working from the command line, when installed into a custom location.

Comment: What does `type chrome` return?

Comment: If, in a Terminal, I type `chrome`, I get `-bash: chrome: command not found`. If I type `open -a chrome`, I get `Unable to find application named 'chrome'`. If I type `open -a 'google chrome'`, Google Chrome opens as expected. What I've described is the default behavior and if doing only `chrome` in a Terminal opened Google Chrome for you, then you either have an _Alias_ assigned or a _Script_ that executes the appropriate command line. BTW `open -a $application_name` should open the target `.app` bundle whether or not it's in the $PATH`.

Comment: @djangofan Here `$ chrome` results in `zsh: command not found: chrome`. The command output of `echo $PATH` might give you a clue where the `open -a` alias is located.